# How to install Empathy 3.x?

Tags: 11.04, empathy

Is it possible and if yes how, to install Empathy 3.0.1 and above in Ubuntu 11.04?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package isn't in official Ubuntu repositories. At the moment you have two choices:

1. Using some non-official package (PPA): Open a terminal and type `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:telepathy/ppa`. If this succeeded, type `sudo apt-get update`. Now you are done and can install Empathy. The current PPA version is 3.0.0-1~ppa11.04+1.
2. Go to the [Empathy tree](http://download.gnome.org/sources/empathy/). There you'll find [version 3.0.1 (tar.gz)](http://download.gnome.org/sources/empathy/3.0/empathy-3.0.1.tar.bz2). You can download and unpack it. Before you continue make sure that the following packages are installed: `gnome-common gettext libglib2.0-dev gtk-doc-tools libxml2-dev libtelepathy-glib-dev libmissioncontrol-client-dev libtelepathy-farsight-dev
   libx11-dev libgtk2.0-dev
   libcanberra-gtk-dev
   libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
   libebook1.2-dev
   libnotify-dev
   libunique-dev
   libgnome-keyring-dev`
   Change into the directory where you unpacked the tar.bz2-file. First you should enter `./autogen.sh`. If this is successful, you can build the software with the command `make` and `make install` installs the software in your system. [Empathy's Install page](http://live.gnome.org/Empathy/Install) has some more information.

Comment: Thank you qbi. Now my second question would be if the dependencies for it will not create a problem with the libraries in 11.04

Comment: As far as I see it Empathy doesn't require a special version of any library. So if you have luck you can use those which are contained in 11.04. However I have not tried myself to install Empathy 3. So it is only guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like only empathy 2.34 is available for Ubuntu 11.04 right now.
http://pkgs.org/package/empathy

Comment: that is the one am using right now but i would like to test a newer one.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to install empathy on Ubuntu 16.04 with simply `sudo apt-get install empathy`.