# How do I update Empathy Messenger?

Tags: 11.04, ppa, empathy

Is there a PPA for Empathy Messenger? I tried adding the [Telepathy PPA](https://launchpad.net/~telepathy/+archive/ppa) but then I realised that that is not the stable PPA, and I got an error message every time I launched the Update-Manager anyway.

So is there a stable PPA for Empathy? Or is there another way to update it?

Thanks very much, and sorry if I shouldn't have asked this here.

Edit: I'm using Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal

Answer (score 2):

The PPA you have linked to has a dependency on Gnome 3 - so this is probably the key reason why it is not working.

I would recommend to clean up using ppa-purge i.e.

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:telepathy/ppa
```

The linked question will give you advice on uplifting the version.  However I would caution against this.  Wait for a couple weeks until Oneiric is released - you will then have the very latest "stable" version automatically installed when you upgrade.

---

Linked Question:

1. [How to install Empathy 3.x?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40459/how-to-install-empathy-3-x)